# How can I add additional styling for a component on a condition

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, javascript-objects

I tried to add additional styles to an component for a condition from props which comes from an input from an other component.
The additional data for the styling comes from `props.alocatedDates` which looks like this:

```
Array [
  Object {
    "dates": "2021-08-31 03:00 AM",
    "name": "Name",
    "style": "blue",
  },
]
```

So the name of the style prop "blue" is in the object as an string and I want to use that information to render the component with additional styles if the condition is right.

<View style={{...styles.container, ...styleCheck()}}>
So for this view I want styles.container as default but if the condition is right also styles.blue.

I tried `style={styleCheck}` and just return `styles.blue` which is defined but even that did not work. I could maybe put the styles directly inside the object or something different?

```
const EventCell = (props) => {
  const styleCheck = () => {
    if (props.id == props.alocatedDates[0].dates) {
      console.log("test")
      return props.alocatedDates[0].style;
    }
   
  };
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => onPressHandler(props.id)}>
      <View style={{...styles.container, ...styleCheck()}}>
        <Text>{props.value}</Text>
        <View style={styles.cellMiddleLine} />
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    height: Sizes.CELL_HEIGHT,
    width: Sizes.CELL_WIDTH,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderTopColor: Colors.grayLine,
    borderRightColor: Colors.grayLine,
    borderBottomColor: Colors.grayLine,
    borderLeftColor: "white",
  },
  cellMiddleLine: {
    backgroundColor: Colors.cellMiddleLine,
    height: 2,
    width: Sizes.CELL_WIDTH,
    alignSelf: "flex-end",
    position: "absolute",
    top: Sizes.CELL_HEIGHT / 2,
  },
  blue: {
    backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
    borderLeftColor: Colors.blueAccent,
    borderLeftWidth: 3,
  },
```

I hope I explained it good enought.

Comment: Try conditional rendering. For e.g ```condition === true ? styles.blue : styles.default``` .

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do it like this

```
const styleCheck = () => {
    if (props.id == props.alocatedDates[0].dates) {
        return props.alocatedDates[0].style;
    }
    return null;
};

return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => onPressHandler(props.id)}>
        <View style={[styles.container, styleCheck() ? styles[styleCheck()] : {}]}>
            <Text>{props.value}</Text>
            <View style={styles.cellMiddleLine} />
        </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try …styles[styleCheck()] instead of …styleCheck() ?

Answer (score 0):

There are differents ways to do that. the most simple is to fix the spread operator and put the style prop that you want add/change. in your component you could do

```
//backgroundColor or whatever style prop
<View style={{...styles.container, backgroundColor: styleCheck()}}>
```

I recommend you that read how the spread operator works  to avoid those little errors :)

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Answer (score 0):

In your JSX View element,

```
<View style={{...styles.container, ...styleCheck()}}>
```

Assuming your condition is "true", `...styleCheck()` will simply return "blue". According to your function and object definition,

```
// Function
const styleCheck = () => {
  if (props.id == props.alocatedDates[0].dates) {
    console.log("test")
    return props.alocatedDates[0].style;
  }
};

// Object
Array [
  Object {
    "dates": "2021-08-31 03:00 AM",
    "name": "Name",
    "style": "blue", <-- You're returning this "string" when condition is true
  },
]
```

So, if styleCheck() returns "props.alocatedDates[0].style", this will render

```
<View style={{...styles.container, ..."blue"}} >
```

Which is a wrong syntax.

---

So I suggest you to change the object type for "style", or use a conditional.

**Option 1 - Change Object:**

```
Array [
  Object {
    ...
    "style": styles.blue
  }
]
```

**Option 2 - Using conditional rendering:**

```
<View style={{...styles.container, styleCheck() === "blue" ? ...styles.blue : null}} >
```

Haven't tested them myself so the syntax may be slightly off, but you should get the idea.